# How can Voldo safely close distance against Hilde?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

Against Hilde, who has an extremely long spear that she likes to stab you with from across the level, I've been having trouble getting in close enough to deal damage.

Against many players, 236A+B is a solid choice because it is a long-ranged low, but skilled players can block this on reaction and punish you pretty hard for it, not to mention that Hilde keeps you so far away that even this probably would come short anyway.

The crouching 3[A+B] is easily sidestepped, and leaves you just as open.

Are all Voldo's long-range moves like this unsafe? I know throwing out random moves in general is not a good practice, but is there some string of attacks that will *safely* close distance? Does Voldo have a move with a secondary Guard Impact effect that will counter Hilde's long-range thrusts?

Comment: People who are good at zoning make life as Voldo very difficult, and people with decent range makes it that much worse. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot whiff moves against Hilde.

If she's not charging her A (charging B), advancing and then sidestepping is very strong, and if you feel like she's not charging her B (charging A), use a medium range poke if you have one. I'm not familiar with Voldo so I can't give you matchup specific knowledge, but that's my experience as a Hilde player.

Alternatively, baiting her C3B with a whiff with fast recovery and then using a Guard Impact to go through it will leave you with plenty of advantage.